The meaning and fulfillment of Deuteronomy 28:68
What is the meaning and the fulfillment of Deuteronomy 28:68?
Is it truth that this is related to black slaves to America?

Deut 28:68 - The LORD will return you to Egypt in ships by a route
that I said you should never see again. There you will sell yourselves
to your enemies as male and female slaves, but no one will buy you.”


Welcome to BHSX.  Many thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.


68 The Lord will send you back in ships to Egypt, by a route which I
told you that you would never see again; and there you will offer
yourselves for sale to your enemies as male and female slaves, but
there will be no buyer.

This prophecy was given to the Israelites as a warning about what would happen "If you are not careful to observe all the words of this law which is written in this book." (v 58) It is not related to slavery in America for the following reasons:

The Israelites were a different group than the various black tribes that were brought to the Americas as slaves.

Those enslaved in the Americas had not made a covenant with the Lord, and were thus not punished for violating the words of the Law.

They did not go to Egypt, but went from Africa to the Americas.

The Lord did not send them.

They did not offer themselves as slaves but were enslaved by force.

Their enslavers found buyers for them.


Thus, at every point, the prophecy does not fit with the situation of black slavery in America. The prophecy may refer to those Jews who fled to Egypt during the Babylonian exile. (Jer. 42-44) Their plight was indeed attributed the their disobeying the Book of the Law. The problem with this interpretation is that Jeremiah warned them not to go, so it does not seem that the Lord sent them.

Some of the Jews could have arrived in Egypt in the holds of the merchants of Tyre, who were selling them on to other places (Joel ch3 v6). It could be said that the Lord had "sent" them by allowing them to be captured.

Hmmm.... I think you mean Joel 4, but thanks. If "sent" is understood in this way, then I suppose God could have sent them to Egypt in Jeremiah's time as well. Jeremiah himself ended up there, though not by choice.

No, we're just in different Bible translations. I'm in the RSV, you must be in one like the New Jerusalem (I've just checked) which divides my second chapter.

The chapter of Deut 28 is divided into two parts:

Deut 28:1-14 - Blessings for Obedience to the covenant
Deut 28:15-68 - Curses for Disobedience to the covenant

The specific curse pronounced upon the Israelites in Deut 28:68 is one of the many, many curses that would occur IF Israel became unfaithful to God.  It is specific to Israel and those of the covenant (as defined in Ex 19-23).
As best I can determine, it has nothing to do with slavery in the USA, largely because no divine covenant-breaking was involved.
Indeed, Israel was unfaithful and many of the curses listed in Deut 28 came to pass, including,

many being taken captive by a foreign nation, Babylon
the remnant going back to Egypt as recorded in Jer 42, 43.


Context:

In Deuteronomy 28, God outlines
blessings for obedience and curses for disobedience to His
commandments. These blessings and curses are directed toward the
Israelites.
Deuteronomy 28:68 falls within the section of curses, where God warns
of severe consequences if the Israelites turn away from Him.

Interpretation:

The verse states: “And the Lord shall bring thee into Egypt again
with ships, by the way whereof I spake unto thee, Thou shalt see it
no more again: and there ye shall be sold unto your enemies for
bondmen and bondwomen, and no man shall buy you.”
The literal interpretation suggests that the Israelites would be
taken back to Egypt (the place of their former slavery) via ships. In
Egypt, they would be sold as slaves, but no one would redeem or buy
them.

Historical Fulfillment:
Historically this may have played out differently. This prophecy has been associated with various events: See this past question.

Babylonian Exile: After the destruction of the First Temple in Jerusalem by the Babylonians, many Israelites were exiled to Babylon.
While not literally Egypt, this exile perhaps represented a kind or reversal of the Exodus journey. (Jeremiah 52:28-30)
Roman Conquest: During the Roman conquest of Jerusalem in 70 CE,
Jewish captives were sent to work in mines or as slaves. Some were
even transported to Egypt. This makes more sense with the prophecy of returning
“with ships.” (Josephus’ “The Jewish War”)

Josephus wrote

Because the soldiers were now growing weary of bloodshed, and survivors appeared constantly, Caesar orders to kill only those who
offered armed resistance and to take alive all the rest. (415) The
troops, in addition to those covered by their orders, slaughtered the
aged and infirm; people to their prime who might be useful they herded
into the Temple area and shut up in the Court of the Women (lcl. (416)
Caesar appointed one of his freedmen as their guard, his friend
Fronto, to decide the fate appropriate to each. (417) All those who
had taken part in sedition and brigandage (they informed against
other) he executed. He picked out the tallest and handsomest of the
lot and reserved them for the Triumph (418). Of the rest, those who
were over seventeen he put in chains and sent to hard labor in Egypt
while greet numbers were presented by Titus to the provinces to perish
in the theaters by sword or by wild beasts; those under seventeen were
sold. (Josephus, “The Jewish Wars”; Book vi 9:2.)


Diaspora: Over centuries, Jews faced dispersion (diaspora) and persecution. Some were enslaved, and Egypt became symbolic of oppression. (Wikipedia)
Transatlantic Slave Trade: Some [1] interpret this verse as foreshadowing
the transatlantic slave trade, where African slaves were forcibly
transported to the Americas (including the United States) on ships.
The parallel that is drawn is that, just as the Israelites were taken to Egypt
in ships, black slaves were taken to America in a similar manner.


You can’t simply take this one verse, impose your belief into it and
then say, see this applies to one specific people and that proves the
point. If this one verse is going to be taken as evidence then ALL the
blessings and curses must be taken and applied to that people.
Therefore it would also need to be demonstrated that ALL the other
curses and the blessings could be applied to black people as well and
NOT to anyone else, through colour or any other determinate means such
as a specific nation. [2]

Under proper and full scrutiny and analyses the verse does not support the claim that the original Jews were black. [3]
Theological Significance:
Beyond the historical context, this serves as a stark warning about the consequences of disobedience and the severity of God’s judgment.
We see the importance of obedience to God’s commandments and the enduring nature of His covenant. We see the need for faithfulness and the consequences of straying from God’s path.
